# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find file field "file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rspec3

I am testing file upload i.e CSV. In my code as well as browser HTML I found file field but while testing the capybara is unable to find the file field. I tried hard and different approaches but unable to fix the problem. Here partial look like this:

```
#add_file_box
  %div.msg
  %h1.page-header
    = "Upload a CSV"
  %h4.title

  = form_tag dummy_path, multipart: true, class: "upload_csv" do
    = hidden_field_tag :dmp_id, @dmp.id
    .form-group
      .input-group
        %span.input-group-btn
          %span.btn.btn-primary.btn-file
            Choose file
            = file_field_tag :file, style: 'line-height: normal',  accept: "text/csv", class: "file_input"
        %input.form-control.input-custom{:readonly => "", :type => "text"}
    .form-group
      = submit_tag "Upload CSV", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "upload_csv"
```

And capybara test look like this

```
 within '.upload_csv' do
     page.attach_file('file', "#{Rails.root}/spec/acceptance/test_uploads/input_output.csv")
     click_button 'Upload'
   end
```

I will be thankful if you can help me fixing this problem?

Comment: is the field visible on the page?

Comment: Yes the field is visible on the page. And the error message looks like this:
`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find file field "file"
from /Users/theKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in block in find'`

Comment: Try taking the page out of it. Like: attach_file('file', "#{Rails.root}/spec/acceptance/test_uploads/input_output.csv")

Comment: @TiagoFarias I had tried it but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Capybara 2x ([capybara issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/546)) doesn't find hidden elements by default.

You can either set ignore_hidden_elements to false:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Or simply add :visible option to your method:

```
within '.upload_csv' do
  attach_file('file', "#{Rails.root}/spec/acceptance/test_uploads/input_output.csv", visible: false)
    click_button 'Upload'
end
```

This solved my problem.

Note: `:visible` option is also supported by most of Capybara methods that internally work with `Capybara::Query` (like `find`, `all`, `has_css?`, `have_selector` etc.)

Comment: So when I tried this, I got the following error. Any ideas?
 ```Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
   Firing a click at co-ordinates [552.5, 617.5] failed. Poltergeist detected    another element with CSS selector ... at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the styling is hiding the file input you can also use the `make_visible: true` option on `attach_file`.

The possible option values are either a `Hash` of CSS values to apply to the file input (in order to make it visible), or `true`, which will attempt a few defaults.

From [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:attach_file):

> make_visible (true, Hash) — A Hash of CSS styles to change before attempting to attach the file,
> if true, { opacity: 1, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' } is
> used (may not be supported by all drivers).