# Capybara Unable To Find Input Field

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, ringcentral

I am using the Ruby gem Capybara for automation purposes (having read the instructions on [this website](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/12/automate-tasks-on-the-web-with-ruby-and-capybara/)). I have a simple script that shows the problem I am having:

```
require 'capybara'
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit 'https://service.ringcentral.com/'
session.fill_in 'LoginName', with: '555-555-5555'
```

I have tried many different suggestions here on SO, and from other websites, with no success. I think this simply has something to do with the RingCentral website itself, because I do not have as much issue with other websites (such as google.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the login field is invisible (opacity: 0 to allow the emptyText to show through from below) Capybara won't find it by default.   You can pass visible: false to fill_in to find non-visible elements, and in this case that will then trigger focus on the element, which will trigger it to change to opacity: 1 and proceed to fill in the data.

```
require 'capybara'
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit 'https://service.ringcentral.com/'
session.fill_in 'login-form-username-field-LoginName', visible: false, with: '555-555-5555'
```

Comment: Tested this and it works! I like the idea of just passing in the visible: false option to individual elements, rather than ignoring all hidden elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278724/capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-file-field-file)! Capybara by default ignores hidden elements. I wanted to post my answer because the other solution was so hard to find because I didn't know that the field I was trying to fill in was a hidden element, so I do not consider this post a duplicate. If you are having a difficult time getting Capybara to find and fill in fields, try setting the ignore_hidden_elements option to false, even if your field is completely visible.

```
require 'capybara'
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
session.visit 'https://service.ringcentral.com/'
session.fill_in 'login-form-username-field-LoginName', with: '555-555-5555'
```

Comment: Setting ignore_hidden_elements to false is a terrible suggestion 99% of the time, if you really need to find hidden elements in this case it's better to pass the visible: false option to fill_in. Most actions won't actually work with invisible elements though since a user couldn't actually interact with them

Comment: The problem for me was not that I was trying to fill in a hidden field. The field is clearly visible if you go to the url. But for some reason, Capybara was treating it as a hidden field. Excellent input on adding the option to the fill_in method specifically though

Comment: It is actually invisible - since the div.x-form-emptyText is displayed over the top of it when its blank to simulate placeholder behavior across all browsers.

Comment: To clarify that -- it's the other way -- the form field is positioned over top the div.x-form-emptyText but it has opacity:0 set so the emptyText shows through.  This means the form field is invisible, but captures mouse clicks on itself to change the opacity to 1 and therefore make itself visible while hiding the emptyText